# Using host system Git when using WSL Remote in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am currently trying to set up a new development environment, using VSCode, WSL, and the WSL Remote Extension. The environment will also utilize Git, and will sign commits via a YubiKey.

I initially tested this out the setup on a Windows 10 machine, using [wsl2-ssh-pageant](https://github.com/BlackReloaded/wsl2-ssh-pageant), and that worked flawlessly. I could sign commits straight from my WSL environment, and everything was awesome. Then I tried implementing this on my work machine, which is running Windows 11... Nothing is awesome.

Apparently there are a whole bunch of issues getting something like this to work on Windows 11, and the author of that library has abandoned the project. I have tried finding an alternative, testing things like npiperelay, wsl-ssh-agent, and a ton of others (too many to list), but the issue always comes back to Windows 11 (and downgrading is not an option).

Therefore, I decided to try a different approach. I can sign commits from Windows 11, using the Yubikey, without issue. So I wanted to get VSCode to use my local Windows 11 Git installation, rather than the WSL one. However, even when configuring git path in the settings, to use the Windows 11 Git, it seems to be using it inside a WSL container, meaning the Yubikey is unreachable; so all signing fails.

I should probably mention that both WSL and Windows 11 has access to the folder.

My current workaround is to do my development in VSCode, and then do all Git commands in a Windows 11 Terminal, which allows me to do signing, but it skips all the VSCode GUI and fancy tools, so I would like to keep everything in a single place.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to develop in WSL via VSCode, using the remote extension, while making VSCode do all Git operations on the host system (completely ignoring WSL)?

Comment: If you take a look at the first diagram in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview you should be able to see that the answer to your question is very likely to be No.

Comment: Which is all extremely relevant, when dealing with actual remote systems. Here we are talking about a WSL environment, meaning it is running on the same machine. So while it is still two different processes running on the same machine, it is still the same machine, which means the option exists.
It may also be that the solution is to take the remote extension out of the equation, but I do not know how VSCode will handle WSL without it.

Comment: WSL is still an isolated system. While "the option exists", who (Microsoft or the community) is going to spend the resources to support that and when is unknown. You can discuss at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues, but probably not here.